# Name of majorite endmember $\ce{Mg3(FeSi)Si3O12}$

Tags: mineralogy

Does the majorite garnet $\ce{Mg3(FeSi)Si3O12}$ have a name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called (unsuprisingly) **majorite**.
This is an IMA-approved name, first described from a meteorite.

More information: https://www.mindat.org/min-2546.html

Comment: But isn't majorite itself a solid solution? I don't see a name for the specific species that has no aluminum in it.

Comment: @g.z. Minerals in general are solid solutions. Endmember chemucally pure minerals are extremely rare in nature. A mineral gets its own name when it’s dominated by a certain component (majorite in this case). This is as close as it gets.

Comment: @g.z. Just like you never see “forsterite” in nature. But if an olivine is sufficiently magnesian, we will call it forsterite even if there’s a bit of Fe and Ni in it.